# Automatically updating a textbox after a radio button is selected in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I've been watching some vids and reading some stackoverflow pages on radio buttons, but I can't find the magic solution I'm looking for.

The answers I've seen on SO generally show you how to create a group of radio buttons and then you have to *press a button to update a text field.*  I'm using italics just to draw attention to that aspect of what I *don't* want.

Basically, I'm creating a simple program in which someone puts in two complex numbers into two different fields, and then selects a radio button to add, multiply, subtract or divide.  I want the operator field to auto-update whenever a radio button is pressed.

Can someone give me a tip or two?  I'm using C#.

TYIA.

Comment: Seems like a misuse of the radio button.  Why not a regular button for each?

Comment: What environment? WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET?  Look for a Checked event on the radio buttons.

Comment: I'm using WinForms, C#, Visual Studio.  Just for the sake of curiosity, let's say I have 20 different things to choose from and they are all mutually exclusive.  Is there an elegant way to do this using late binding and reflection?  I think a series of IF statements would be kind of cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to subscribe to the check_changed event of the radio button.

```
rbSum_CheckChanged(object sender, Eventrgs e)
{
  if(rbSum.Checked == true)
   {
      txtField.Text = "+";
   }
}

rbSubtract_CheckChanged(object sender, Eventrgs e)
{
  if(rbSubtract.Checked == true)
   {
      txtField.Text = "-";
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works great, thank you.  I was trying to go into the properties window of textBox1 and trying to enter in a variable.  Needless to say this didn't work.  Is there a more elegant way to do this using "Reflection"?  I saw a video in which the presenter said, "Reflection" will make it so you don't have a long list of "if" statements.

Comment: you could create one generic check_changed event and subscribe all radio button to it, then switch on the radio button name, but this method should be fine for what your doing

Comment: DidIReallyWriteThat... Can you provide a snippet?  I'd like to learn more advanced methods.